# how to call other class static method static

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

i want to call other class method  but its show me error. my other class is static class and static method please help me this how to solve this error.  when compiler UHRCryptoManager its show above error

> {"The type initializer for 'UHRServices.Manager.UHRCryptoManager'
>   threw an exception."}
>
> Service1.svc

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService , IService1
{
   public UHRResponse RequestApiToken(string CallerId)
   {
       UHRResponse response = new UHRResponse();

       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CallerId))
       {
            if (CallerId.Length >= 15 && CallerId.Length <= 32)
            {
                string UserAgent = Context.Request.Browser.Platform;
                string ip = GetUserIP();

                string ApiToken = UHRCryptoManager.GenerateApiToken("sadassdasdasdsadsd", "WinNT", "::1", 636549893023357954);
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> other class
> ```

```
public static class UHRCryptoManager
{
    public static string GenerateApiToken(string callerid, string userAgent,string callerip, long ticks)
    {
        string hash = string.Join(":", new string[] { callerid, userAgent, ticks.ToString() , callerip });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the whole definition for `UHRCryptoManager`? The error you are getting normally indicates an error in the static class constructor.

Comment: @Adeel Aijaz : does `UHRCryptoManager` class have any static property ?